# Maximum of the count of the grouped elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Database is AdventureWorks.

```
select COUNT(*) as 'Number of times a product is sold at same quantity' 
from
  Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
group by 
         OrderQty, ProductID 
order by 
         COUNT(*) desc
```

This returns data like this:

```
Number of times a product is sold at same quantity
--------------------------------------------------
4279
3216
3095
2376
2334
2319
2234
2201
2121
2025
1712
1488
1396
1161
1044
```

and other 2600+ rows.

I am interested in getting 4279 as output.

I cannot apply Max as the it doesn't work with aggregate function or subquery. I tried anyway. Didn't work.

I am guessing I cannot, since count(*) is not a column. But if there is a way:

**How can I get max of such output?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `TOP` to limit the number of results

```
select TOP 1 COUNT(*) as 'Number of times a product is sold at same quantity' 
from  Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
group by  OrderQty, ProductID 
order by  COUNT(*) desc
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*different records but have the same thought*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d7ba/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*uses CTE and Window Function*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d7ba/7)

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
WITH results 
AS
(
  select COUNT(*) as [Number of times a product is sold at same quantity],
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rank_no 
  from   Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
  group   by OrderQty, ProductID 
)
SELECT [Number of times a product is sold at same quantity]
FROM   results
WHERE  rank_no = 2
```

- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: @AnubhavSaini - Why ask a question that states "I am interested in getting 4279 as output." if that is not your actual goal? It just wastes the time of answerers that first have to answer the question you actually asked then change it to answer the question you meant to ask.

Comment: you can do that using `CTE` and a `Window Function` see here, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d7ba/7

Comment: Make this answer a subquery, but change the 1 to 2.  Then select the min().

Comment: @MartinSmith My reasoning was that if I can get top most, I could find next one too.

Comment: @AnubhavSaini - Well from your followup question that clearly wasn't the case. Next time please ask your real question.